# The rasool (swl) recieving gifts

Tags: hadith-interpretation

It is narrated in: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3946

> "A man from Banu Fazarah gave a gift to the Prophet (ﷺ) of she-camel from his camels which they had taken at Al-Ghabah. So he reciprocated for it with something in return, but he was upset with it. So I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), upon [this] Minbar saying: 'Indeed one of the men from the Bedouins gave me a gift so I reciprocated for it to the extent of what I had. Then he became very upset with me. By Allah! After my experience with this Bedouin man, I shall not accept a gift from anyone except from a Quraishi, Ansari, Thaqafi, or Dawsi.'"

What is the proper understanding of this narration? Did the rasool (swl) exchange a gift with someone else and the bedouin got mad? Likewise, why would he not accept a gift from them ever again just because of this interaction. Lastly, why does he only mention these 4 tribes? After all, we know that he had accepted Maria the Copt and her sister as gifts from the current ruler of Egypt. Is him saying this not contradictory to the former?

Comment: No the prophet accepted the gift. Note this hadith (in the version you've shared) was reported via imam al-Bukhari who quoted it in his al-Adab al-Mufrad. It also appears a second time in Jami' at-Tirmidhi [here](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3945) and Sunan abi Dawod, an-Nassa-i and elsewhere.